# Correct behaviour despite no null terminated string?

Tags: c, string

This is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char some_string[4] = "ball";
    char * pointer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    strncpy(pointer, some_string, sizeof(char) * 4);
    printf("String is %s\n", some_string);
    printf("String in the pointer is %s\n", pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I purposefully declared a char array of size 4 and left not space for the null terminator. Whenever I printed it out, I got weird (unprintable) values appended to the end of it (as expected). However, I also expected the same thing for the `pointer` variable because it should lack the null terminator (since it only has space for 4 `char`, so no space for `\0`. However, whenever I run this code, `some_string` is always messed up, yet after about 50 tries `pointer` is perfectly fine, despite (from my view) not having a null terminator. Why is this?

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour. Your expectation is not correct. You cannot expect any specific result when Undefined Behaviour is in play.

Comment: One possible explanation is that on some systems the heap manager only allows certain fixed block sizes for memory allocations. So perhaps `malloc(4)` cannot allocate exactly 4 bytes, and will get 8 or 16 bytes minimum from the heap manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` format specifier in `printf()` expects a null terminated string.

In this case you have undefined behavior(UB). Sometimes UB gives expected results.

Side note:

`sizeof(char)` is a constant across all platforms(1 byte) so no need to specify it during memory allocation.